# How do I render a nested Array with React.js?

Tags: arrays, reactjs, nested, render, chunks

I am new to react.js and I have stumbled upon a subject I can't wrap my head around. I have a long array of items which I want to display in two different rows, which is why I take chunks out of this array and add them to a nested array without key and values like so:

```
constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            characters: [["Anakin","Darth Vader","Snoke"], ["Darth Maul", "Yoda", "Luke Skywalker"]],
        }
    }
```

In the render function of the "Characters" component I use the map function and what I want is each array to be passed to the component "Subarray":

**Characters component**

```
 render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {this.state.characters.map((item, index )=> <Subarray key={index} title={item}></Subarray>)}
            </div>
        )
    }
```

And then in the "Subarray" component I want to add a html element to every element in that array:

**Subarray component**

```
export class Subarray extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
               {this.props.title}
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

I can't get each element of the array to be wrapped within a div element:

**Output:**

```
<div><div>AnakinDarth VaderSnoke</div><div>Darth MaulYodaLuke Skywalker</div></div>
```

Comment: What exactly you are looking for ? i mean is there any error? whats the issue ?

Comment: `this.state.characters` is your entire `var array` ?

Comment: what is `character`?

Comment: The output is displayed like this: ```<div><div>AnakinDarth VaderSnoke</div><div>Darth MaulYodaLuke Skywalker</div></div>```. They don't get wrapped within a html element

Comment: yes, `this.state.characters` is my entire `var array`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this, assuming `this.props.title` contains `["Anakin","Darth Vader","Snoke"]` :

```js
export class Subarray extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
           <div>
            {this.props.title.map((each, index) => <div key={index}>{each}</div>)}
           </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that you have to change Subarray to be something like

```js
export class Subarray extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
               {this.props.title.map((item, index) => {
                  return <div key={index}>{item}</div>
               })}
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

in this way you loop through each item in the subarray and render every one of them